# Create own math symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, captions

i need some additional math symbols in latex. I did draw them in eps and include them with:

```
\newcommand*\triangleLeft{\ensuremath{\includegraphics{../triangleLeft}}}
\newcommand*\triangleRight{\ensuremath{\includegraphics{../triangleRight}}}
\newcommand*\triangleProp{\ensuremath{\includegraphics{../triangleProp}}}
```

This works fine for the most things. But it does **not work for captions** and notes (package: todonotes).

Do you have any better idea? Here is a screenshot of my symbols:

[image: my new symbols]

The x is subscript and does not belong to the symbol.

Kind regards,
Max

Update:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{stackengine, amsfonts} %


% Non of these work... :()
%\newcommand{\triangleLeft}{\ensuremath{\includegraphics{triangleLeft}}}
%\newcommand{\triangleLeft}{\mathrel{\text{\includegraphics{triangleLeft}}}}
%\newcommand{\triangleLeft}{\mathord{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{-0.3ex}{\scriptstyle\leftharpoonup}{\largetriangleup}}}

\begin{document}

\sansmath
 $ \triangleLeft_{\!x}$

$\triangleLeft_{\!x}$

\begin{figure}

% Next line fails!
\caption{$\triangleLeft_{\!x}$}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The error is either (for the first two definitions):

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.25 \caption{$\triangleLeft_{\!x}$}
```

or

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\stackinset #1#2#3#4#5#6->\def \conditioned@inset 
                                                  {\stack@delim #5\stack@del...
l.25 \caption{$\triangleLeft_{\!x}$}
```

for the third version.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Excuse me but into the symbol of the triangle, what are? I've never seen these symbols in mathematics enviroments. Could you add a complete code, please? Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: I'd say something like `\newcommand{\triangleLeft}{\mathrel{\text{\includegraphics[height=0.8\strutbox]{../triangleleft}}}}`

Comment: You may need \protect for things like \caption and todonotes to prevent it from expanding too soon.

Comment: @egreg, still does not work in captions.. :(

Comment: @Sebastiano The symbols represent that $x$ is in the symmetric difference of two sets. In the case of triangleLeft, $x$ is in the left set, and in the other case analog.

Comment: @nopx If you plan to use it in captions or titles, use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: @nopx Thank you very much. I have not known the meaning of the symbol.

Comment: @Sebastiano It is newly defined by me for my thesis because I did not found any better symbol. You cannot know it. :)

Comment: Answers and questions have different 'homes' on the site: a self-answer is very welcome, but should be posted as such to help future vitisors

Answer (score 9):

You can obtain these symbols very simply with `Mnsymbol` and the `stackinset` command from `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{stackengine, amsfonts} %
\newcommand{\leftharpoontriangle}{\mathord{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{-0.3ex}{\scriptstyle\leftharpoonup}{\largetriangleup}}}
\newcommand{\rightharpoontriangle}{\mathord{\stackMath\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{-0.3ex}{\scriptstyle\rightharpoonup}{\largetriangleup}}}

\begin{document}

\sansmath
 $ \rightharpoontriangle_{\!x}$

$\leftharpoontriangle_{\!x}$

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very nice.

Comment: Does also not work in captions. :( See above ^^ But thanks a lot, very nice symbols.

Comment: @nopx: to make it work in captions, use `\caption{\protect\leftharpoontriangle}`.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks! Do you have any idea how to make it scale appropriately in super or subscript?

Comment: Probably defining a series of sizes with `\mathpalette. I don't have time at the moment to test the idea, but I'll do that this week-end.