# Wasysym astrological symbol does not resize appropriately in math (e.g. subscript/superscript)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, scale, wasysym

I am using the symbol `\sagittarius` from `wasysym` in math mode, and it does not resize appropriately e.g. when it appears in a subscript or superscript. How can I fix this?

This question is a special case (not a duplicate) of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554460/scale-own-math-symbol-image-appropriately).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `wasysym` package allocates a symbol font, but doesn't declare all symbols as math ones, only those that the author deemed likely to be useful as math symbols.

You can supplement the list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\DeclareMathSymbol\sagitmath  {\mathord}{wasy}{99} %or \mathbin or \mathrel ...
\begin{document}

$\sagitmath a^{\sagitmath^{\sagitmath}} b_{\sagitmath}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The symbol `\sagittarius`, like other astrology symbols in `wasysym`, works both in text and in math mode. While the math mode version does not scale appropriately, the text one does, so you could use:

```
\newcommand{\sagittariusmath}{{\text{\sagittarius}}}
```

Now `$a_\sagittariusmath$` will look better than `$a_\sagittarius$`.