How do I create a symbol that looks like capital pi with a squiggle?
I apologise for this question, but I feel this notation would be very convenient for my purposes. I will continue with my attempts, and post if I feel I manage. Would it be possible to superimpose two math symbols on each other? I was trying to do some tricks with tikz but they don't work like math symbols.


Can you describe the use case or what should the extra part be? How tall should it be?

Have you had a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573850/how-to-create-a-new-math-operator https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413073/creating-custom-mathematical-symbols https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148366/creating-a-custom-math-symbol-from-scratch https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552008/create-own-math-symbol ?

@azetina I need to define some new universal properties that resemble product and coproduct, but not really. Since people usually have intuition for products and coproducts, I thought this would be a good choice.

@azetina Quarter the size of the height of limb. I thought for the sake of aesthetics, I was trying to get the dagger symbol pierce the top part. (with the cross part above the bar)

One way to superimpose characters is with \ooalign.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\dagprod}{%
    \ooalign{\hfil\raisebox{.23ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\dagger$}}\hfil\cr$\prod$\cr}}
\begin{document}

$A\dagprod B$

\end{document}


You might want to express the dimension for \raisebox in terms of the x-height rather than as an absolute like points.  If the type size for the job is changed to 12pt, a fixed 1pt will no longer be suitable.

Good point @barbarabeeton. Fixed.

You possibly mean something like the following.
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\daggerprod}{}{%
  \DOTSB\mathop{\vphantom{\prod}\mathpalette\daggerprod@\relax}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\daggerprod@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth
    \raisebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle 0.1\else 0.2\fi \height}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{%
        \scalebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle 1.4\else 1\fi}{$\m@th#1\dagger$}%
      }%
    }%
    \hidewidth\cr
    $\m@th#1\prod$\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\daggerprod_{n=0}^{100}A_n
\]
\hspace*{\mathindent}$\daggerprod_{n=0}^{100} A_n$

\end{document}

The fleqn option and the \hspace instruction are used just to make a smaller picture showing the symbol in display and text styles.


Thank you very much! Either of them works.
